# Allow multiple authentication methods in claims based web application

Tags: claims-based-auth

Web applications using CMA (Classic Mode Authentication) need to be setup with different Zones if it is to accommodate different types of CMA methods. This is called 'extending a web application'. In web apps using CBA (Claims Based Authentication), how do you allow for multiple authentication methods, as you do not have to 'extend it'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you already created a webapplication with claim based authentication.

- Open **Central Administration**
- Go to the webapplication list en select your webapplication
- In the ribbon - click **Authentication providers**

[image: Here you can enable Win authentication, FBA and anonymous access]

Answer (score 0):

When I enable both {NTLM,forms} This causes my web service calls to throw 401 unauthorized error codes. If I disable forms then all webservices calls work.